# How to get Grand Total in Base Currency

Tags: magento2, checkout, grand-total

I am using the below code to get Sub Total and Grand Total but it is returning total in **Display Currency**.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
 
$subTotal = $cart->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
$grandTotal = $cart->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
```

How to get the grand Total in Base Currency in case **Default Currency** is different than **Display Currency**.

I am able to get the **Base Currency Total** by below code, but it is not exactly the same as displayed on "You will be charged for" on the payment page.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

$grandTotal = $cart->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();

$priceCurrencyFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory');
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
 
$currencyCodeTo = $storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrency()->getCode();
$currencyCodeFrom = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getCode();

$rate = $priceCurrencyFactory->create()->load($currencyCodeTo)->getAnyRate($currencyCodeFrom);
$baseTotal = $grandTotal * $rate;
```

Difference of value is shown in image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function convertToBaseCurrency($price)
        {
     $Value = $price * $rate;
    
    //   step1 : get currenct currency
         
            $currentCurrencyCode = $this->storeManager
                                    ->getStore()
                                    ->getCurrentCurrency()
                                    ->getCode();
   // Step 2 : get base currency
            $baseCurrencyCode = $this->storeManager
                                 ->getStore()
                                 ->getBaseCurrency()
                                 ->getCode();
   // Step 3 : get rate
            $currencyRate= $this->currencyFactory
                         ->create()
                         ->load($currentCurrencyCode)
                         ->getAnyRate($baseCurrencyCode);
  //  step 4 : get value
            $Value = $price * $currencyRate;
    
            return $Value;
        }
```

Comment: Check my updated question and I am getting base total through this code but it has some difference of value, when I compare it with **You will be charged for value on payment page**

Comment: what's the difference. Share the associated values. It should be more related to some configuration and not a code issue.

Comment: plz check this image: https://imgur.com/a/ADNpsla

Comment: This is due to rounding effect.

Comment: your rates are 99.7766 and due to rounding its taking a lesser value. hence there is that amount different. In your estimate code you need to applying rounding to 2  decimals.

Comment: $grandTotal = $cart->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();  add this line $grandTotal=round($grandTotal)

Comment: after applying round now the value is increased as compared to the value coming from default knockoutJs component.